# Эффект при наведении которые появляютсья слои соответсвенные блокам.Со стороны которое навел user

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет.

Помогите реализовать эффект который при наведении на блок накладываетсья **цвет** такой же как и сам блок.То есть если в блоке стоит картинка красного цвета то при наведении должен накладыватсья панель в красном котором написан произвольный текст.

> И самое важно что если user навел с левой стороны то и панель с
>   соответсвующим цветом должен накладыватсья с левой стороны

Эффект взят [**отсуда**](https://kreatik.co/websites-and-web-applications/websites/) помогите реализовать подобное очень прошу

```css
.related {
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.related > a > img {
  max-width:240px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="related">
<!--   green -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Limes.jpg/339px-Limes.jpg">
    <span>green bg</span>
  </a>
<!--   red -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498144846853-60ca2d43853b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=acf655f657c7582cb46fc9a6a625e50b&w=1000&q=80">
    <span>red bg</span>
  </a>

  <!--   yellow-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://www.sneakerfiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/shoe-palace-under-armour-curry-4-yellow.png">
    <span>yellow bg</span>
  </a>
  
  <!--   orange-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2015/11/8/0/BXSP03H_Orange-Honey-Glazed-Carrots_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.462.suffix/1447093964946.jpeg">
    <span>orange bg</span>
  </a>
  
  <!--   grey-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://cdn.thesolesupplier.co.uk/2017/09/Jordan-11-Grey-Suede-Premium-03.png">
    <span>grey bg</span>
  </a>
  
  <!--   blue-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://s3.envato.com/files/158244028/1.jpg">
    <span>blue bg</span>
  </a>
  
  <!--   green -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Limes.jpg/339px-Limes.jpg">
    <span>green bg</span>
  </a>
  
    <!--   grey-->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="https://cdn.thesolesupplier.co.uk/2017/09/Jordan-11-Grey-Suede-Premium-03.png">
    <span>grey bg</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Попытка у меня внизу на ссылке пока что единственный разумный вариант работаю над ним .
Ссылка на [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/KxwYqY)

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? В определении цвета? В определении стороны? Что пытались сделать?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko пожалуйста не ставьте минусы .То что я делаю и у меня получилось я добавил  с ссылкой на  _Codepen__.Цвет не очень то принципиальен в основном мне нужен этот ховер эффект написать .Спасибо

Comment: Так я минус и не ставил. Судя по коду в codepen, вы уже почти все сделали: определение стороны захода, анимация. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что-то вроде того, что вы хотели

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdpeMa).

```js
// - Noel Delgado | @pixelia_me

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("li"),
  _nodes = [].slice.call(nodes, 0);

var getDirection = function(ev, obj) {
  var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
  };

  var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
  var pointCursor = {
    x: ev.pageX,
    y: ev.pageY
  };
  var distanses = [];
  distanses.push({
    d: getDistance(pointCursor, {
      x: obj.offsetLeft,
      y: ev.pageY
    }),
    t: 3
  });
  distanses.push({
    d: getDistance(pointCursor, {
      x: ev.pageX,
      y: obj.offsetTop
    }),
    t: 0
  });
  distanses.push({
    d: getDistance(pointCursor, {
      x: obj.offsetLeft + rect.width,
      y: ev.pageY
    }),
    t: 1
  });
  distanses.push({
    d: getDistance(pointCursor, {
      x: ev.pageX,
      y: obj.offsetTop + rect.height
    }),
    t: 2
  });
  var d = distanses.sort((a, b) => a.d - b.d)[0];
  return d.t;
};

var addClass = function(ev, obj, state) {
  var direction = getDirection(ev, obj),
    class_suffix = "";

  obj.className = "";

  switch (direction) {
    case 0:
      class_suffix = "-top";
      break;
    case 1:
      class_suffix = "-right";
      break;
    case 2:
      class_suffix = "-bottom";
      break;
    case 3:
      class_suffix = "-left";
      break;
  }

  obj.classList.add(state + class_suffix);
};

// bind events
_nodes.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener(
    "mouseenter",
    function(ev) {
      addClass(ev, this, "in");
    },
    false
  );

  el.addEventListener(
    "mouseout",
    function(ev) {
      addClass(ev, this, "out");
    },
    false
  );
});
```

```css
.container-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-inner ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container-inner ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container-inner ul li {
  background-color: rgba(256, 18, 156, 0.9);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: 290px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-inner ul li .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(26, 88, 156, 0.9);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.container-inner ul li .info p {
  color: #fff;
}

.in-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.in-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: in-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-top .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-top 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-right .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-right 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-bottom .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-bottom 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-left .info {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
  animation: out-left 300ms ease 0ms 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes in-top {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes in-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes in-bottom {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes in-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes out-top {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes out-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes out-bottom {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes out-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container-inner'>
  <ul class="blue">
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class='info'>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое ну вот обьясните мне пожалуйста как вы реализовали данную анимацию __return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));__ эту математическую формулу сами написали или как ?

Comment: @Demon__ANT Это просто формула вычисления расстояния между двумя точками. Геометрия 8 класс, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: благодарью ....